# Data not rendering if I Include a State as my Props; React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**This is the useState for the Data**
*if I removed this state from the code, it will render fine.*

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([] as Product[]);
```

**This is the code for Mapping/ Rendering the Data**

```
<SingleProduct {...product} key={index} cart={cart} setCart={() => setCart} />
```

**Types**

```
export type Product = {
  name: string;
  price: string;
  image: string;
  id: string;
};

export type Cart = {
  cart: Product[];
  setCart: (cart: Product[]) => any;
};
```

```
export const SingleProduct = ({ cart, setCart }: Cart, { ...product }: Product) => {(
      <button onClick={() => { setCart([...cart, product]);}}>
          Add to Cart
      </button>
      <button onClick={setCart(cart.filter((item) => item.id !== product.id))}>
         remove from Cart
      </button>
  )};
```

> Note that if I remove the cart and setCart function, my code works perfectly fine.

I've been debugging this code for more than an hour now, if someone can please help me. It would be a big help!

**PS: Still learning TypeScript and I tried making a Shopping Site**

Comment: what is the error you're getting? also, can you create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with codesandbox?

Comment: That is the weird part. I'm not getting any error. It's just the data is not rendering

Hold on, I will create it now.

Comment: with this much information it will be difficult. over the top of my head, i believe it is probably because of shallow compare react uses

Comment: I've removed unnecessary code from earlier, maybe you could help me again?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can make a codesandbox since i need more context, you can replace your data with some mocks, that works.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cannon-3m6exm?file=/src/index.tsx

Hello sir, I've created the codesandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Here's [my forked version](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-morning-dihzjm)

Based on your codesandbox, I think I have found your issue.

1. Instead of spreading props in `Home.tsx`, try something like this, note, we are passing reference of `setCart` function. Also, cart is not required to be passed, `setState` passes previous state automatically :

```
{products.map((product, index) => (
   <SingleProduct key={index} product={product} setCart={setCart} />
))}
```

2. In your `SingleProduct`, instead of specifying types for each method, you can create a simple interface and pass it to `React.FC`, so all your types will be inferred correctly. Also, `setState` has a different signature than what you're using:

```
interface ISingleProduct {
  product: Product;
  setCart: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Product[]>>;
}

export const SingleProduct: React.FC<ISingleProduct> = ({ setCart, product }) => {
```

3. On click functions can be modified as follows (idk why, somehow your `...product` was coming as empty, maybe need to look more closely):

```
// add to cart
<button
  className="add"
  onClick={() => {
    setCart((prev) => [...prev, product]);
  }}
>

// remove from cart
<button
  className="add"
  onClick={() =>
    setCart((cart) => cart.filter((item) => item.id !== product.id))
  }
>
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your solution. I didn't know that it was possible to pass the props like that since I only saw people do something like extends and use the "&".

Thank you for your help! I'm just starting to learn typescript so I don't have a deep understanding of it. Anyways thanks!

Comment: if this worked for you, please upvote and mark it as correct answer, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that instead of:

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([] as Product[]);
```

You should do:

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState<Product[]>([] as Product[]);
```

Or try:

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState<Product[]>([]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it just need some tweaking in order for the first one to be worked!  I appreciate your help